# VB6 search option in ComboBox

Tags: search, combobox, vb6

How can I use a ComboBox to search a field from a database table when I type in it. I'm using this code, but it's not working the way I want:

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()

    Dim sValue As String

    sValue = Combo1.Text

    If Combo1.Text <> "" Then
        Set rsFList = New ADODB.Recordset
        Combo1.Refresh

        rsFList.Open "SELECT name FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '%" & sValue & " %' ORDER BY name", StCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
        If rsFList.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Do While Not rsFList.EOF
                Combo1.AddItem rsFList.Fields("name").Value
                rsFList.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        Combo1.Text = sValue
    End If

End Sub
```

An example of what I want:

In a database table, I have this data in the column `name`:

- aaa
- aab
- aac
- aad
- aft
- agh
- bgr
- bfs

So when I type **a**, it should update the list and show this data:

- aaa
- aab
- aac
- aad
- aft
- agh

Again, if I type the second letter, **aa**, the list will update to:

- aaa
- aab
- aac
- aad

... and so on.

How can I do it?

this it ll select from one column call **name**, if i have another column in this table call **ID**  and i want but the value in text box how can i do it.

```
rsFList.Open "SELECT ID, name FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '%" & sValue & " %' ORDER BY name", StCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

An example:

- ID   - Name
- 1    - aaa
- 2    - abd
- 3    - abc

in ComboBox it should showing only **name** but when i select **ID** will showing in text box, how can do it?

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if instead of "it's not working as I want", you described exactly what is happening and what you want to happen. One problem I see is when you modify the combobox list the text will be cleared which I assume is why your are setting the text at the end of the method. However that will cause the event to fire again and you are going to get an out of stack space error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An review of your code shows the following:

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()

    Dim sValue As String

    sValue = Combo1.Text

    If Combo1.Text <> "" Then
        Set rsFList = New ADODB.Recordset
```

So far, so good. However, the next line doesn't make sense. The Refresh() method is used to repaint the control. My guess is that since later on you are adding items to the combo box, you actually want to remove all the items here.

```
        Combo1.Refresh
```

So you actually, you should be using: `Combo1.Clear`

The SQL in the next line looks a bit wrong:

```
        rsFList.Open "SELECT name FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '%" & sValue & " %' ORDER BY name", StCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Look carefully at: `LIKE '%" & sValue & " %'`. I presume that you want to find all the values that are prefixed with your characters. But you are matching any characters  at the *beginning* of `sValue`, and then you are matching a space, then any characters at the *end* of `sValue`. For instance, if `sValue` was "aa", this would evaluate to: `LIKE '%aa %'`.

I am guessing you would want: `LIKE 'aa%'`. So the replacement line should be: `rsFList.Open "SELECT name FROM goods WHERE name LIKE '" & sValue & "%' ORDER BY name", StCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic`

```
        If rsFList.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Do While Not rsFList.EOF
                Combo1.AddItem rsFList.Fields("name").Value
                rsFList.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        Combo1.Text = sValue
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for solve my problem, i try it and it's working. i have another query another see the orginal Question i ll edit it.

Comment: Your second question makes the same mistakes you made in the first question. This is really confusing, since you have already approved my answer. Also, I *think* I understand the second question, but I shouldn't have to guess. If I have guessed wrong, then I have wasted your time and my time. Can you do this as a new question based on the answer I gave you, and rewrite it to be an simple as possible? Thanks, Mark.